# mongo sort after limit after sort - Not working

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a collection, from which i get particular type of users using $query
Then I need sort them according to user_id ascending and limit them to 2000

From these I need the max user_id, so I sort them in descending order and limit to 1.

But this second sort forgets the limit of 2000 and sorts over over the entire cursor from find().

Any work-around?

```
$cursor = $collection   ->find($query)                // too many entries
            ->sort(array('user_id'=>1))   // go ascending
            ->limit(2000)                // got our limited qouta
            ->sort(array('user_id'=>-1)) // go descending to get max
            ->limit(1);          // the one with max(user_id)
```

Comment: You have a semicolon on the third line. Is that a copy/paste error or is it also present in your original code?

Comment: oh yes, copy paste error, thanks for pointing out, corrected

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your cannot do a sort and then a limit and then a sort. The Cursor object is exactly that and it will not run the query until you iterate to the first result via `getNext()` which is either run manually or within a `foreach` loop not only that but `sort` is just a property of the object as such making two sorts just overwrites the property.

The best way to achieve what your looking for is:

```
$doc = $collection->find($query)->sort(array('user_id' => 1))
       ->skip(1999)->limit(1)->getNext();
```

That will always pick the highest `user_id` (which occurs at the end in this sort) of the group, which will give off the same results as doing two sorts.

Comment: this one looked like correct. I tried collection->find->sort->skip(1999)->limit->getNext as well as collection->find->sort->skip(1999)->getNext. Both are giving same (but incorrect) answer. Will post back when i figure it out.

Comment: we can do $collection->find()->sort()->skip(1999)->getNext(); 
the limit(1) in between can be definitely skipped

Comment: @davneet Yea I didn't think of that, getNext() of course just gets the next document so the limit is inert there.

Answer (score 3):

How about using skip():

```
$cursor = $collection   ->find($query)  
        ->sort(array('user_id'=>1))   
        ->limit(2000)                
        ->skip(1999);
```

Comment: +1 Wouldn't a `limit(1)` here work just as well since only the first of the docs after the 1999 skipped ones is needed?

Comment: the above code still gives me 2000 records in the cursor... that would mean ill have to iterate over all those to get to the last record

Comment: ups, sorry. find(...)->sort(...)->skip(1999)->limit(1) is probably what you need.

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason behind sort-limit-sort-limit approach?

Can't you just do

```
$cursor = $collection ->find($query)
            ->sort(array('user_id'=>-1))
            ->limit(1);
```

**EDIT:** Also, only the last `sort` applied to the cursor has an effect. (This line is present in `pymongo` docs [here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.sort), which makes sense.)

Comment: the point of first sort-limit is to get the first 2000 records out of all. the second sort-limit simply gets the max out of these 2000. Ur code will give me max out of all records from find()

Comment: Ok, now I get it. You're trying to get the 2000th document in ASC order that matches the query. You should know that when you apply `sort` on a `cursor`. No documents are retrieved (therefore sorted) until you actually iterate over that cursor. You can use `skip` but that becomes a slow operation. Best approach is to use range based queries in situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code in [php5](/questions/tagged/php5) and [mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb) latest build:

```
$doc = $collection->find($query)->sort(array('user_id' => 1))
    ->skip(1999)->limit(1)->getNext();
```

It stops working when I use `->skip(1999)->limit(1)` after `sort()`

The cursor `$doc` does give me values . I tried braking it down into this:

```
$doc = $collection->find($query)->sort(array('user_id' => 1))
$doc = $doc->skip(1999)->limit(1);
```

That worked. May be you should try that in new versions.

Answer (score 0):

[Answer by Sammaye](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14425636/1045444) is correct.

You can still achieve the way you wanted. You can use aggregation framework, as it executes one stage after other stage and so on.

```
$doc = $collection->aggregate(array(
    array(
      '$match' => $query,
    ),
    array(
      '$sort' => array(
          'user_id'=> 1
      ),
    ),
    array(
      '$limit' => 2000
    ),
    array(
      '$sort' => array(
          'user_id'=> -1
      ),
    ),
    array(
      '$limit' => 1
    ),
));
```