# mongo db - can't get right syntax to sort documents by a specific field

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the following php code that works:

```
            global $m, $db;
            $collection = $db->locations;
            try{
                    $cursor = $collection->find();
                    return $cursor;
            } catch(MongoCursorException $e) {
                    return false;
            }
```

Now I'd like to sort the results in ascending order by a field called "name".

This is what I've tried:

```
            global $m, $db;
            $collection = $db->locations;
            try{
                    $cursor = $collection->find().sort({name:1});
                    return $cursor;
            } catch(MongoCursorException $e) {
                    return false;
            }
```

But I'm getting an error that says:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /var/www/html/myapp/models/locations_model.php on line 23
```

Any tips?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongo sort after limit after sort - Not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423646/mongo-sort-after-limit-after-sort-not-working)

Comment: change `.sort(...)` to `->sort(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`$cursor = $collection->find()->sort(['name' => 1]);`

Your error is because you are not sending an array to the sort, which it expects, see [PHP mongocursor sort](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.sort.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try
$cursor = $collection->find()->sort(array('name' => 1));
```

For more detail [Click here](https://derickrethans.nl/cursors-in-mongodb.html).