# mongo sort after limit after sort

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to get the latest 5 elements out of a mongo database in a chronological order. The database is very big, so performance is a criteria.
Using the C# API and the .Net framework my code would be:

```
var query = parts
    .AsQueryable()//Asking for data elements                   
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.DateTime)//get the latest elements
    .Take(5)//only get the latest 5 elements
    .OrderBy(p => p.DateTime) //order these elements chronologically
;
var returnparts = new ObservableCollection<Part>(query);
```

According to [mongo sort after limit after sort - Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423646/mongo-sort-after-limit-after-sort-not-working) this doesn't work because only the latest `.OrderBy` is used, the other one is overwritten.

Possible other solutions would be:

- Using `.Skip()` as supposed in [mongo sort after limit after sort - Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423646/mongo-sort-after-limit-after-sort-not-working). 
  Code would be:

  ```
  int noSkip = parts.AsQueryable().Count() - 5;//calculate how many elements to skip
  if (noSkip < 0) { noSkip = 0; }//if there are less then 5 elements
  var query = parts
      .AsQueryable()//Asking for data elements                   
      .OrderBy(p => p.DateTime)//get the latest elements
      .Skip(noSkip)//skip everything except the latest 5 elements
  ;
  var returnparts = new ObservableCollection<Part>(query);
  ```

  This solution doesn't work for me, as it has poor performance, as it looks at every part in the database twice. (once for counting, once for skipping)
- Turning the Collection over /Sorting it with an own algorithm (e.g. a foreach-loop). This solution doesn't seem the most elegant one, neither does it have high performance, as the sorting would be done client-side.

Is there any high-performance solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Actually yor first query should work. The second order is applied only on 5 items. I have tried  similiar query out on my collection and it works.

Comment: @MaksimSimkin You are right, I just thought this couldn't work, as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423646/mongo-sort-after-limit-after-sort-not-working stated so.